# Como implementar múltiplos drivers de autenticação

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou construindo um sistema onde é necessário haver dois tipos de autenticação, a primeira referente a usuários comuns, que irão acessar a frente da loja, e a segunda para administradores, que irão acessar o ambiente de administração.

O problema:
por padrão o Laravel 5 possui apenas um driver de autenticação, o que possibilita que usuários comuns logados na frente da loja tenham acesso ao ambiente de administração, e vice-versa.

Identificar o que é usuário e o que é administrador é até fácil com um sistema de níveis (roles), porém não é tão efetivo quanto a divisão destas sessões.

Como posso implementar uma segunda sessão de autenticação apenas para administradores? como por exemplo: `Auth::admin()`

Comment: Por que o uso de roles não é efetivo nesse caso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode "emular" uma nova Auth Class.

O componente Laravel Auth é basicamente o Illuminate\Auth\Guard class, and this class have some dependencies.

Então, basicamente você tem que criar uma nova Guard class...

class CilentGuard extends AuthGuard
{

```
public function getName()
{
    return 'login_' . md5('ClientAuth');
}

public function getRecallerName()
{
    return 'remember_' . md5('ClientAuth');
    }
}
```

E um ServiceProvider para inicializar a class, passando as dependencias.

```
<?php 

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;
use Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\PasswordBroker;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\DatabaseReminderRepository;
use ClientGuard;
use ClientAuth;

class ClientServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{

    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerAuth();
        $this->registerReminders();
    }

    protected function registerAuth()
    {
        $this->registerClientCrypt();
        $this->registerClientProvider();
        $this->registerClientGuard();
    }

    protected function registerClientCrypt()
    {
        $this->app['client.auth.crypt'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new BcryptHasher;
        });
    }

    protected function registerClientProvider()
    {
        $this->app['client.auth.provider'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new EloquentUserProvider(
                $app['client.auth.crypt'], 
                'Client'
            );
        });
    }

    protected function registerClientGuard()
    {
        $this->app['client.auth'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            $guard = new Guard(
                $app['client.auth.provider'], 
                $app['session.store']
            );

            $guard->setCookieJar($app['cookie']);
            return $guard;
        });
    }

    protected function registerReminders()
    {
        # DatabaseReminderRepository
        $this->registerReminderDatabaseRepository();

        # PasswordBroker
        $this->app['client.reminder'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new PasswordBroker(
                $app['client.reminder.repository'], 
                $app['client.auth.provider'], 
                $app['redirect'], 
                $app['mailer'], 
                'emails.client.reminder' // email template for the reminder
            );
        });
    }

    protected function registerReminderDatabaseRepository()
    {
        $this->app['client.reminder.repository'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            $connection   = $app['db']->connection();
            $table        = 'client_reminders';
            $key          = $app['config']['app.key'];

            return new DatabaseReminderRepository($connection, $table, $key);
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return array(
            'client.auth', 
            'client.auth.provider', 
            'client.auth.crypt', 
            'client.reminder.repository', 
            'client.reminder', 
        );
    }
}
```

Neste Service Provider, eu coloquei alguns exemplo de como criar um 'novo' componente para lembrar a senha. Agora você precisa criar duas novas facades, uma para autenticação e outra para os lembrar a senha.

```
<?php 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class ClientAuth extends Facade
{

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() 
    {
        return 'client.auth';
    }
}
```

E

```
<?php 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class ClientPassword extends Facade
{

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() 
    {
        return 'client.reminder';
    }
}
```

Claro que, para o lembrar senha, você precisa criar a tabela no banco de dados, a fim de trabalhar. Neste exemplo, o nome da tabela deve ser client_reminders, como você pode ver no método registerReminderDatabaseRepository no Service Provider. A estrutura da tabela é a mesma que a tabela original. Depois disso, você pode usar seu ClientAuth da mesma maneira como você usa a classe Auth. E a mesma coisa para ClientPassword com a Password Class.

```
ClientAuth::gust();
ClientAuth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password));

ClientPassword::remind($credentials);
```

Não se esqueça de adicionar o seu provider de serviços para a providers list de serviços no arquivo `app/config/app.php`.

Comment: Amigo, só uma dúvida. Onde eu deveria colocar essa nova Guard Class? no caso, CilentGuard.